# Can't remove weird return character / line ending in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a PHP function that generates an XML file from my data. Some of which was submitted via textarea fields.

When I create the XML file the textarea fields are displaying with an unusual carriage return at the end of the value. I've tried removing with the following methods, none of which do anything.

```
trim($value)
str_replace( "\n", "", $value)
str_replace( "\r", "", $value)
str_replace( "\n\r", "", $value)
str_replace( "\r\n", "", $value)
preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $value)
```

even tried strip_tags($value) and html_entity_decode($value) in case it was something weird i could strip out.

One thing that did remove it was removing all but alphanumeric characters via a regex but thats no use since my users will want to use a lot of characters like dashes, brackets, single and double quotes, etc.

Are there any other methods of removing weird characters like this? Or any other strange carriage returns that I can remove via code?

Comment: Try `preg_replace('/\R+/', ' ', $value)`

Comment: Nope. still there I'm afraid. its the weirdest thing! Can't figure out what return character it would be. Thank you for your quick response though.

Comment: Can you paste that char here in the *question body*?

Comment: No i just tried and the content  appears without any return after the content. 

here is anyway. The weird returns are just after the "content."

<label>test 1: </label><some_data>test content. </some_data>
<label>test 2: </label><some_data>test content.</some_data>

Comment: It does not matter what it looks like. If you can copy/paste it, it would be "visible" in the raw text. You may try yourself to paste it at https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/

Comment: So it appears to be something like \2029 or &#8233; but I've just tried removing both, still there. Unless I'm not removing it correctly. Whats the best way to remove it?

Comment: preg_replace('/\R+/u', ' ', $value) was the answer! The others didn't work. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Hi, hopefully I have. I upvoted it yesterday but forgot to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
$value = preg_replace('/\R+/u', ' ', $value)
```

Here, `\R` matches any Unicode line break sequence.

Also, see the [`/u` modifier reference](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> **`u (PCRE_UTF8)`**
>   This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern and subject strings are treated as UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar cases. In my case, there was a non-breaking-space unicode character which looked like a space, but wasn't.

What you could do it iteracte over all the characters in the string, and inspect them one by one so see what's odd. This will probably not solve your problem directly, but at least help you get to the solution I hope.

```
for( $i = 0; $i < strlen($value); $i++ ) {
    $chr = $value[$i];
    echo "{$i}: [$chr}] [".ord($chr)."];\n";
}
```